# From 3D to 2D - where to start?

Tags: slam, navigation, map-saver, map-server, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to convert some 3D-maps made with rgbdslam/rtabmap-slam into 2D gridmaps, but really don't know where to start. Can someone please answer me some question to get this done?

1.) rgbdslam: can save octomaps over GUI but the file extension of saved files is pcd instead of bt/ot. Why?

2.) read a lot about saving maps while processing with "rosrun map_server map_saver -f filename". Tried that while rgbdslam/rtabmap where running - response is always: "waiting for map". Do I have to install octomap_server into the same workspace as both slams? And if thats the solution, will I finally have a 2D gridmap by running this command?

As you can see on my questions, I'm a newbie. I know this question has been asked and answered multiple times before though i was not able to make it. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

THANK YOU

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236422/from-3d-to-2d---where-to-start?/) by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-06-08**:
`rtabmap` has `proj_map` output topic, which is the 3D point cloud projected on the ground: `rosrun map_server map_saver map:=/rtabmap/proj_map`

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately still "waiting for map"... rtabmap is running and recording, both are "sourced" from the same setup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. That's a bug, I thought I already fixed. The workaround is easy though: Just change the extension to .ot in the save dialog.
2. octomap_server has some capability to downproject the map. See the description of the `map` topic on its [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server#Published_Topics). Should be easy to subscribe to this topic and save the map. Maybe there is even an existing node for that.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thanks for the fast reply Felix! Thats exactly my problem, how do I subscribe to a (/the map) topic? I've read this a bunch of times before but haven't found a detailed explanation yet. Do you mind to tell me how to continue with this (or the keywords to look for in ros tutorials)?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-08**:
I recommend you to read [the tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) 6, 10, and 11 or 12. Anything more specific depends on how you want to use the map.

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-13**:
Ok, done. map_saver subscribes now from topic /projected_map, octomap_server provides the data, rqt_graph looks good. But it seems octomap_server doesn't subscribe from rgbdslam: I remapped topic with , but when I press ...

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-13**:
... "send model" in gui, terminal responds with: "no Subscribers, sending of clouds cancelled". rqt_graph only shows one arrow with "tf" headline and that is not a
topic, right? what do I miss?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-14**:
The remap seems correct. Could you post the rqt_graph image? Have you had success saving to file, when specifiying the extension .ot?

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-14**:
rqt-graph: [http://imgur.com/iiiA59y](https://imgur.com/iiiA59y)
saving octomap with .ot extension works fine. We firstly started rgbdslam+octomap_server+map_saver, recorded an octomap, send model. After sending the model, this error message occurs (from octomap_server): ...

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-14**:
... " MessageFilter [target=/map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.octomap_server.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information."

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-14**:
Hm, I don't see where you would have done something wrong. Actually rgbdslam should send the transformations with the clouds, but maybe they are too old for the octomap server to use? I never had this problem though...

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-14**:
An alternative workflow, if you are mapping offline, would be to load the saved octomap file on startup of the octomap_server. You just need to add an `arg="mapfile.ot"` attribute in the `node` tag in octomap_mapping.launch.

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-15**:
I figured out saving the file as octomap over gui doesn't work: the mentioned workaround works with an octomap downloaded from [uni freiburg](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/datasets/octomap/), but fails when loading a processed octomap from rgbdslam. The error message is:

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-15**:
... [ERROR] [1465988735.566811374]: Could not read OcTree in file, currently there are no other types supported in .ot.
...[ERROR] [1465988735.566877078]: Could not open file /home/ubuntu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/testmap.ot

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-15**:
I downloaded rgbdslam_v2 from indigo branch, if that makes any difference ...

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-15**:
That's because it's a color octomap. Octovis handles them by default, but the octomap server doesn't. You can easily build it from source and activate a [define](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/jade-devel/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServer.h#L69) to get it working.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-15**:
Otherwise you'd mostly need to change all occurrences of `ColorOcTree` to `OcTree` in rgbdslam's corresponding [header](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/indigo/src/ColorOctomapServer.h)  and [cpp](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/indigo/src/ColorOctomapServer.cpp) file.

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-06-27**:
Thank you very much for your effort, Felix! Now everything works fine.